# Moving objects in the sky tonight 27th March 2020

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, identify-this-object, night-sky, nasa

Multiple moving objects not in a line. The are staggered single line and in groups of two or three. One or two moved downward. They had a dim light orangey colour.

It was not obvious that these satellites as normally observed.

Also observed witnessed whilst on the mobile phone with family people in the street.

Moving from the area of canis minor travelling left two or three minutes apart. There were over 50 of them.

What could have it been?